# R Vegan package: Excluding NA values from permanova (adonis)

Tags: r, vegan

I am trying to generate PERMANOVAS using the adonis function from the vegan package. I am testing many different factors to see which ones are significant. For certain factors in my metadata some samples are NA. Obviously when I try to generate a permanova for these factors, I get an error. I don't want to remove rows that have NA values from the dataset because they are only in certain columns, and I would like to include these samples for analysis of other factors. I also do not want to fill the NA columns with another value (ie 0) because this may effect the results. I am looking for a way to exclude the values that are NA when generating each permanova.

I tried both

```
propData<-as.data.frame(t(otu_table(otu)))
propData_bray<-vegdist(propData, "bray")

adonis(formula = propData_bray ~ pH, data=new_meta, na.action=na.exclude)
```

and

```
adonis(formula = propData_bray ~ pH, data=new_meta, na.action=na.omit)
```

The otu table has no NA values.
Here is an example of the metadata:

| sample | factorA | factorB | factorC | factorD |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | yes | 3 | NA | 0.5 |
| 2 | yes | 4 | no | 1 |
| 3 | no | NA | yes | 0.05 |
| 4 | yes | 3 | yes | 0.7 |
| 5 | NA | 0 | NA | 1.5 |

for factorA I would include samples 1-4, factorB 1-2 & 4-5 , etc.

Comment: You may check the issues [here](https://github.com/vegandevs/vegan/issues/302) and [here](https://github.com/vegandevs/vegan/issues/319)

Comment: I'm not really following the documentation. From what I gather I have to use the source code from github? But I have never had to do that before and I have no idea what I need to change to accomplish this

Comment: `na.action` is indeed only implemented in unreleased vegan 2.6-0 (only in github).